# Resume the bookmark after a value to change

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, bookmarks

Please I really need help, I just post this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217897/questions-about-activities-scenario-in-wf but nobody answered.

My question, How can I wait the approve value to become true which I read it via method in WCF, then resume the workflow ?

I'm using rehosted workflow for the user!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to poll a WCF method and do something when true is returned you could use a `DoWhile` activity with a `Delay` activity and your call to the WCF method inside of it.  Set the `Delay` activity duration to the amount of time between each polling attempt and do something to exit the `DoWhile` loop when a value of true is returned.